# Could not find driver when I trying to display my PHP

Tags: raspbian, python, php, sqlite, database

After going through a few tutorials of displaying data to php from python and my sqlite database, I keep getting this error and don't know how to fix it. I'm in need of urgent help.

**Error Message**
Execption: could not find driver

This is my code:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Sensor Data Log</TITLE>
</HEAD> 
<BODY>
<?php
try {
     $db = new PDO('sqlite:/var/www/ledDB.sq3');
     $db->exec(
        "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sensor (Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, ID INTEGER, Sensor TEXT, Log DATETIME)");
     $db->exec(
       "INSERT INTO sensor (ID, Sensor, Log) VALUES ('1', 'Red Sensor', 2014/07/02 19:19);".
       "INSERT INTO sensor (ID, Sensor, Log) VALUES ('1', 'Red Sensor', 2014/07/02 19:20);".
       "INSERT INTO sensor (ID, Sensor, Log) VALUES ('1', 'Red Sensor', 2014/07/02 19:21);");

     $table = "<tr><th>Id</th><th>ID</th><th>Sensor</th><th>log</th></tr>";
     $result = $db->query('SELECT * FROM sensor');

     foreach ($result as $row) {
        $table .=
            "<tr><td>" . $row['Id'] . "</td>" . 
            "<td>" . $row['ID'] . "</td>" .
            "<td>" . $row['Sensor'] . "</td>" .
            "<td>" . $row['Log'] . "</td></tr>";}

      print "<table border=1> $table </table>";
      $db = NULL;}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    print "Exception : " . $e->getMessage();}?></BODY></HTMl>
```

Hope you guys could help out with it as soon as possible, thanks in advance, guys.

Comment: I see no relevance to the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: I'm using Raspberry Pi as hardware side, joan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While PHP's PDO itself extension is provided by the `php5` package, not all of its database-specific drivers are. You'll have to install the PDO sqlite driver separately:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-sqlite
```

Comment: Wow, it works, Another Code. Thanks alot, Another Code.